# Изменение загружаемого по умолчанию ядра Ubuntu на удалённом сервере

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

Есть удаленный сервер, на котором установлена `Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus)`. Версия ядра `2.6.32-042stab141.3`. Установил новое ядро по инструкции https://lumpics.ru/how-to-update-kernel-in-ubuntu/ ВТОРЫМ способом (через git). Проверил командой `dpkg --list | egrep "linux-image|linux-headers"` получил вывод:

```
ii  linux-headers-4.7.0-040700rc6         4.7.0-040700rc6.201607040332             all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.7.0
ii  linux-headers-4.7.0-040700rc6-generic 4.7.0-040700rc6.201607040332             amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.7.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic          4.4.0-51.72                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-4.7.0-040700rc6-generic   4.7.0-040700rc6.201607040332             amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.7.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic    4.4.0-51.72                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Отмечу, что ядра с текущей версией `2.6.32-042stab141.3` там нет в принципе
Пытался редактировать файл `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Изменив строку с `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` на `GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"` Действовал в слепую, т.к. сервер удаленный, и я не могу посмотреть какие пункты меню grub на каком месте.
Далее использовал

```
update-grub
reboot
```

Версия ядра не изменилась после перезагрузки. Как заставить ubuntu загружать новую версию ядра?

Comment: Эта версия ядра означает, что сервер хостится на OpenVZ и у вас нет никакой возможности изменить ядро. По этой же причине настройки grub тоже ни на что не будут влиять (grub не используется вообще)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Я так понимаю, что ты не решал проблему прокачки себя в сборке ядра, а патчил старую ОС, чтобы что-то работало. Так?